# How to bind set of reports to report viwer?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, rdlc

I want to print a set of invoice for my application. So I need to display all invoices in report viewer before they print. are there any methods to bind multiple reports to same report viewer using crystal reports or rdlc. I try rdlc but I couldn't find any way to do that. 
please any one can  provide code sample or instruction in C#.net it's worth for me.

thank you.......

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path in reportviewer from code behindlike so:

myReportViewerControl.LocalReport.ReportPath = "path/foo.rdlc";